# Упаковать число в строку с минимальной длиной

Tags: алгоритм

Условия:

1. Упаковка должна быть обратима, само собой
2. Символы - из набора некодируемых для URI
3. Ни при каких обстоятельствах длина результирующей строки не может быть больше длины текстового представления исходного числа

Предлагается такой вариант: перевести в 36-ричную СС. 36 просто потому, что столько символов в наборе `"0-9,a-z"`. То есть, например, число `1234567890987654321` превратится в `9do1sjhjpekg`. Можно увеличить основание засчёт введения "цифр" **.** (точка), **-** (дефис) etc, но принципиально это уже мало чего изменит.

Ещё версии?

Comment: архиватор + шифр подстановки, арифметика по модулю, кодирование напр: http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Код_Хаффмана

Comment: Хотел было написать "архиватор не предлагать", но не думал, что кто-то всерьёз может это сделать... OK, добавлю третье условие.

Comment: Мне кажется, что теоретически наилучшей упаковкой будет запись в системе по основанию `n`, где `n` — общее количество некодируемых для URI символов. Разве нет?

Comment: @KoVadim, потому что подставляется в URL.

Comment: @VladD, это я и сделал, ну разве что исключил некоторые символы для улучшения визуального представления. Хотя автоматике всё равно, конечно. Просто вдруг что ещё придумается :)

Comment: Я бы использовал динамическое кодирование Хаффмана (динамика даст нам выполнение пункта 3), переведенное в 64-битную ситстему, как советовал @KoVadim.

Comment: @klopp, URL в общем случае регистрозависим. Сравните например http://bit.ly/A и http://bit.ly/a .

Comment: В общем случае да, но можно ли это гарантировать, если ту сторону я не контролирую?

Comment: Другая сторона должна уметь декодировать данные? если да, тогда не нужно переживать. Если же другая сторона не декодирует данные, тогда тоже переживать не нужно - если они и будут искажены, никто не узнает. Если же другая сторона передает данные дальше и при этом их модифицирует - это проблема, но в общем случае наказывают другую сторону. Главное идти по стандарту.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А почему не использовать и заглавные? То есть, диапазон `0-9a-zA-Z` и плюс ещё два символа (например точку и подчеркивание). В результате будет 64 символа, что сильно упростит перевод. И самое веселое - это просто будет модификация `base64`. (хотя какая это модификация, просто данные нужно подготовить).

Comment: > Главное идти по стандарту.

Да, что-то я запарился не по делу :) В процессе склепался [побочный продукт](http://ato.su/url/), вроде работает, по основанию 62 :)